# Where are the images for the Messages.app status bubbles located on filesystem?

Tags: macos, messages

I'm assuming Messages.app uses images for their status bubbles like other graphics in the app. Here are the bubbles I'm talking about:

[image: status bubbles image]

If my assumption is correct, then where are they located on the filesystem? I'm trying to find the images to use them as a resource for a local app I'm creating. I'm on 10.10.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Path is: /Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/

1. Open up **Applications**
2. Right-click on **Messages**
3. Click **Show Package Contents**
4. Double-click on **Resources**

However, rather than taking Apple's graphics, you're better off creating your own. Can't be too tough to create two circles with borders. Preview will do it for you in 5 mins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that is the first place I looked.  I can't seem to find them in that folder. I thought it would be easier to use pre-existing graphics. But, you're right, it is taking a bit longer to find them rather than creating my own. Anyway, I'd still like to know.